# Spring Asciidoctor Extensions not in correct repo?

Tags: maven, spring-restdocs

Good afternoon guys,

I've been trying to get spring-asciidoctor-extensions to work with my documentation but for some reason maven can't find the dependency.

The error i got after my build attempt:

```
Failed to execute goal org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-maven-plugin:1.5.5:process-asciidoc (generate-docs) on project organization: Execution generate-docs of goal org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-maven-plugin:1.5.5:process-asciidoc failed: Plugin org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-maven-plugin:1.5.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find io.spring.asciidoctor:spring-asciidoctor-extensions:jar:0.1.1.RELEASE in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I checked thier [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-io/spring-asciidoctor-extensions) and looked around to find out that theres nothing in the maven repo (obvious from error) and in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211766/using-tabs-in-asciidoc-spring-rest-docs) found that the repo is in  https://repo.spring.io/release. Is there a way to reference a dependency to a repo directly? If not what can i do?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `repo.spring.io` repository to your `pom.xml`.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

With that declaration in place you will be able to resolve this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.spring.asciidoctor</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asciidoctor-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

More details in [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html).

Note: it is not possible to explicitly associate this dependency with that repository. Maven walks through the repositories in order of their declaration until a given dependency is resolved (or not) however if all of your other dependencies are resolved from Maven Central then the only dependency left to be resolved from `repo.spring.io` will be `spring-asciidoctor-extensions`.

Comment: Didn't worked within the <asciidoctor-maven-plugin> dependencies. Tho it was able to find it if not in the plugin dependencies. Not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well. My misconception at first was that I expected the `dependencies` to be resolved from the `repositories` section. However turns out that it's rather the `pluginRepositories` section. Like so:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```